# Static Class with attributes and synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

I know that there are alot of nearly equal answers here on StackOverFlow but they didn't fit my needs.

Given the following code example:

(inner class)

```
static class OutgoingFileTransfer implements Runnable {

File sendThisFile;

outgoingFileTransfer(File sendThis) {
    this.sendThisFile = sendThis;
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    //Send the file...  
}
```

}

I know, that the synchronized method will lock the whole class, but only if the run() method has been called. If I do the following:

```
Thread a = new Thread(new OutgoingFileTransfer(new File("c:/.../file1"))).start();
Thread b = new Thread(new OutgoingFileTransfer(new File("c:/.../file2"))).start();
```

Could it be, that Thread a initialises `file1` and BEFORE entering the synchronized method, and then Thread b interrupts, set `file2` and joins the run() method? This would mean, that file1 never would be sent. Right?

And is there any way to prevent this?

I know the cheap way: Make everything non static an add a `boolean iAmCurrentlySendingAFilePleaseWaitInTheQueueTillTheOtherFileTransferFinished`, so that all goes sequential. But I think there will be nicer ways to do this. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I think that boolean could be more descriptive, how about `iAmCurrentlySendingAFilePleaseWaitInTheQueueTillTheOtherFileTransferFinishedBecauseIfYouDontThenWeWillRunIntoConcurrencyIssuesAndThoseJustArentFun`

Comment: @Rogue: Sorry, name too long. :P

Comment: @Andres: If the class itself is static, the methods also have to be, or am I false? But anyway, this was a fault of mine. Changed "static" -> "synchronized"

Comment: It seems to me, that if you synchronize Runnable#run() then you render the whole thing single-threaded anyway.

Comment: @TrudleR, the fact that the class is static does not make its methods static.

Comment: Making the run method synchronized is meaningless if there's no other synchronized method in the class. If this is the complete definition, the `synchronized` modifier is useless. Moreover, since each OutgoingFileTransfer object is going to be used by a single thread, there's no need for synchronization (unless this is just part of the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thread a = new Thread(new OutgoingFileTransfer(new File("c:/.../file1"))).start();
Thread b = new Thread(new OutgoingFileTransfer(new File("c:/.../file2"))).start();
```

Creates two different threads with two different `OutgoingFileTransfer` objects. Each will have its own version of `sendThisFile` and will operate on it. Synchronization and locking come into play when multiple threads act on the same object at the same time. In your case, there is no danger of a race condition, the two threads are independent and run parallely.

***Edit:***
*Static Classes in Java:*
Java allows only static inner classes, not static top level classes. A static class does not make everything in it static. 
From The Java tutorials:

> In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class
>   that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging
>   convenience.

So a static class can be instantiated like any other class, can have static and non static members line any other class and the behaviour of static and non static members are like any other class.

So in your case, there are two `sendThisFile` independent attributes from teo independent instances of the class. In this case, the behaviour is same as if `OutgoingFileTransfer` were a top level (therefore non static) class.

Comment: I know that for normal objects, but OutgoingFileTransfer, in this case, is a static class? Doesn't it prevent from building a unique object?
I am a bit confused acctualy because I didn't even know that you can create an instance of a class like this.

Comment: Java allows only static inner classes, not static top level classes. A static class does not make everything in it static. From [The Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html): _In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience_. So a static class can be instantiated like any other class, can have static and non static members line any other class and the behaviour of static and non static members are like any other class.

Answer (score 1):

I think the crux here is the misunderstanding of the `static` qualifier for nested classes.

You can only declare those classes as `static` that are nested in other ones, meaning

```
class A {
    static class B {
    }
}
```

Outer classes can never be static (in this example, `A`). `static` for classes means, that the nested class *does not need an instance of the outer class around it*. Meaning if `B` is static, you can do

```
A.B b = new A.B();
```

if it is not, you have to do:

```
A a = new A();
A.B b = new a.B();
```

This is heavily opposed to the concept of `static` with members and methods.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Guess I have to go with my boolean idea.